# R - how to locate fail in parallel loop (pblapply)

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing, lapply, display

I'm working in R, and using the function **pblapply()** to make parallel processing. I love this function because it shows a progress bar (very useful for estimate very long execution).

Let's say I have a huge dataset, that I split in 500 smaller subdatasets. I will share them through different threads for parallel processing. But if one subdataset generate an error, the whole **pblapply()** loop failed, and I don't know which of the 500 small subdatasets generated the error. I have to check them one by one. When I do such loop with the R base **for()** function, I can add `print(i)` that will help me locate the error.

**Q)** Can I do something similar with **pblapply()**, display a value to tell me which subdataset is currently executing (even if several are displayed at the same time, as several subdatasets are manipulated at the same time by the different threads). It will save my time.

```
# The example below generate an error, we can guess where because it's very simple. 
# With the **pblapply()**, I can't know which part generate the error, 
# whereas with the loop, testing one by one, I can find it, but it could be very long with more complex operation.

library(parallel)
library(pbapply)

dataset <- list(1,1,1,'1',1,1,1,1,1,1)

myfunction <- function(x){ 
   print(x)
   5 / dataset[[x]] 
}

cl <- makeCluster(2)
clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c('dataset', 'myfunction'), envir = environment())

result <- pblapply(
   cl  = cl, 
   X   = 1:length(dataset), 
   FUN = function(i){ myfunction(i) }
)

stopCluster() 
# Error in checkForRemotErrors(vaL) : 
# one node produced errors: non-numeric argument to binary operator

for(i in 1:length(dataset)){ myfunction(i) }
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
# [1] 4
# Error in 5/dataset[[x]] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be to use `tryCatch` on the part that can cause an error, e.g.:

```r
myfunction <- function(x){ 
    print(x)
    tryCatch( 5 / dataset[[x]] , error=function(e) NULL)
}
```

This way, you get NULL (or whatever you choose) for cases with an error, and can deal with that later in your code.

```r
which(lengths(result)==0)
```

would tell you which list elements had an error.

You could then examine what happened exactly and implement code that properly identifies and deals with (or prevents) problematic input.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it could be a good compromise.